# Cannot retieve the_content() and the_author() - both returning empty strings

Tags: loop, author, the-content, single, wp-head

I am creating the following code to display open graph meta data in the header of my single.php page

```
add_action('wp_head', 'mycode_add_og_meta_tags', 5);

function mycode_add_og_meta_tags () {

?>
    <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>

    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); echo ' ('; _e('Source:', 'mydomain'); the_author(); echo')'; ?>"/>

    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_content(), '<p>'); ?>"/>

    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('single') ?>"/>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
}
```

However, both `the_author()` and `get_the_content()` do not return any data; yet `the_title()` and `the_post_thumbnail_url()` do return data.

Moreover, in the 'body' of the single.php file, I am able to retrieve all the aforementioned information.

I am suspecting that this has to do being inside the loop, so my questions are:

1. If it has nothing to do with the loop, how can I retrieve the missing aforementioned values?
2. If my approach is incorrect because I am retrieving that information outside the loop, then:

   - How come title and thumbnail work?
   - How can I set the open graph meta data (og), before getting into the loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get_the_content and the_author have to be in a loop so you would need to use other functions to get the content you need

```
global $wp_query;
$post = $wp_query->post;
$page_id = $post->ID; // page ID
$page_object = get_page( $page_id ); // page stuff
$author_id = $post->post_author; // author ID

$page_content = $page_object->post_content;
$author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id);
```

Comment: hmmm, `$post` is set in the loop so not sure you idea will work at all

Comment: oops, edited to use $wp_query

Comment: Both this solution: `global $wp_query`, and your original solution: `global $post`, worked

Comment: Simply use `get_post` to be on safe side. Also check if you are on single page or not!

Comment: my fault for being vague. I guess the first problem is with the OP assumption that there is even a post that can be looked at. Search pages might not have any results at all, and for such archive pages he will probably want to have something else in any case. `get_queried_object` is kinda more "neutral" way to get the object being queried without relying on the loop related global variables;